# Read CSV file and use StringTokenizer

Tags: java, string, csv, tokenize

This is a simple homework assignment that has been driving me crazy for the last few days. If I were to use a couple of Arrays I could have done it a while ago but having to use the StringTokenizer is driving me nuts.

The main problem I am having is reading the CSV file. I don't know how to do it and previous searches online have only brought forward super intense solutions that are too much for a beginner like me to handle.

This is my code. As you can see, I don't know whether use `.nextLine()` or `.NextToken()`. Neither seems to work.

For those wondering the assignment is basically reading the first 4 products separated by commas and reading the rest of the rows as the rating of those 4 products. Basically 6 rows with 4 columns. The first row is the products the rest are the ratings.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductRating {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    Scanner fileIn=null;
    try{
        fileIn = new Scanner(
                 new FileInputStream("C:/Users/Cristian/Desktop"));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e)
     {  // This block executed if the file is not found
        // and then the program exits
    System.out.println("File not found.");
    System.exit(0);
    }

    //If Opened File Successful this runs
    String products = "A";
    String rantings ="0";
    System.out.println("Gathering Ratings for Products");

    do{

        String delimiters = ", ";

        StringTokenizer gatherProducts[]=new StringTokenizer[inputLine, delimeters];
        gatherProducts=fileIn.nextLine();

    }while(fileIn.hasNextLine()==true);

}   

}
```

Comment: +1 this is how a question about a homework should be asked.

Comment: String tokenizer is depreciated, I am surprised that a teacher would request that you use it. Split is the thing these days.

Comment: Careful, there is more to a CSV than the delimiters. You also have escape characters.

Comment: @Marichyasana Use of `StringTokenizer` is discouraged but it is not deprecatred.

Comment: anyway why is this question here

Comment: @DanielLerps - Why is it discouraged ?

Comment: Because it does not support regular expression as the `split()` method of `String` does. See the Java documentation of `StringTokenizer`: "StringTokenizer is a legacy class that is retained for compatibility reasons although its use is discouraged in new code. It is recommended that anyone seeking this functionality use the split method of String or the java.util.regex package instead."

Answer (score 8):

easy way with `Streams` API in java 8 (csv with a header line):

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/Users/Cristian/Desktop"); // path to folder
    Path file = path.resolve("file.csv"); // filename 
    Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(file);
    List<String[]> list = lines
            .skip(1)
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can also use the `flatMap` function to retrieve all elements in a single list

```
         List<String> list = lines
            .skip(1)
            .map(line -> line.split(","))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: @Cristian Reyes do you use java 8 ? did you try my answer ?

Comment: Readers copying this slick solution should be aware, though, that  CSV allows for the separator characters comma and newline to appear in the data if properly escaped. `Files.lines()` as well as `line.split(",")` will produce wrong results in these cases.

Comment: This solution will not strip double-quote enclosures off the data fields.  Nor will it resolve double-double-quotes where these occur.  For example:
123,"Strings","He said, ""I didn't do it""."

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't think you're interpreting the `StringTokenizer` method calls / return types correctly. The array doesn't make much sense to me.

You want to iterate over each line in the csv file, right? You can just create a new `StringTokenizer` on each step of the loop, and use that to grab what you want from each line.

Clean up your `do ... while` loop so it looks more like this:

```
final String delimiter = ", ";
for(int lineNumber = 1; fileIn.hasNextLine(); ++lineNumber) {
    String csvLine = fileIn.next();
    if (lineNumber == 1) {
      // this is your special case for the first line, handle it!
      continue;
    }

    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(csvLine, delimiter);
    while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
      String token = tokenizer.nextToken();
      // do stuff with the tokens!
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I split up the rows? Am trying to get the first row by itself and tried using .substring() but that didn't work. I need to get the ratings from the rest of the rows convert them into number and then average them. Know anyway to do that?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a special case for the first line. Just remember that each line of text in your file corresponds to a string in java. That's what the scanner is used for here.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are using array of StringTokenizer? Try this.

```
try{
            StringTokenizer st=null;
            FileReader inputFileReader = new FileReader("C:/Users/Cristian/Desktop");
            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(inputFileReader);
            String inLine = null;
            while((inLine =  inputStream.readLine())!=null){
                st = new StringTokenizer(inLine, ",");
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());
                System.out.println(st.nextToken());
            }
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
         {  // This block executed if the file is not found
            // and then the program exits
        System.out.println("File not found.");
        System.exit(0);
        }
```

Comment: It's telling me "unhandled exception type IOexception" in that while line.

Answer (score 0):

Use [SuperCSV](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/readers.html), example follows, from [this page](http://supercsv.sourceforge.net/examples_reading.html):

```
private static void readWithCsvBeanReader() throws Exception {

        ICsvBeanReader beanReader = null;
        try {
                beanReader = new CsvBeanReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILENAME), CsvPreference.STANDARD_PREFERENCE);

                // the header elements are used to map the values to the bean (names must match)
                final String[] header = beanReader.getHeader(true);
                final CellProcessor[] processors = getProcessors();

                CustomerBean customer;
                while( (customer = beanReader.read(CustomerBean.class, header, processors)) != null ) {
                        System.out.println(String.format("lineNo=%s, rowNo=%s, customer=%s", beanReader.getLineNumber(),
                                beanReader.getRowNumber(), customer));
                }

        }
        finally {
                if( beanReader != null ) {
                        beanReader.close();
                }
        }
}
```

You will need to define a [bean](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7224-javabeans-1.01-fr-spec-oth-JSpec/) for your business object, and use it in lieu of CustomerBean.